# How do I add CORS to a compojure-api app?

Tags: api, clojure, cors, compojure, compojure-api

How can I add CORS to this code snippet?

```
(def app
    (api
        {:swagger {:ui   "/docs"
                   :spec "/swagger.json"}}

       (GET "/route-a" [] "a")
       (GET "/route-b" [] "b")
       (GET "/route-c" [] "c")))
```

I would like to use https://github.com/r0man/ring-cors and have tried this, but it did not seem to do anything. I would like to see the response header contain Access-Control-Allow-Origin but it is missing.

```
(-> (api
   {:swagger {:ui   "/docs"
              :spec "/swagger.json"}}

   (GET "/route-a" [] "a")
   (GET "/route-b" [] "b")
   (GET "/route-c" [] "c"))

  (wrap-cors :access-control-allow-origin #"http://localhost:81"
             :access-control-allow-headers ["Origin" "X-Requested-With"
                                        "Content-Type" "Accept"]
             :access-control-allow-methods [:get :put :post :delete :options]))
```

Comment: I think you need allowed methods too

Comment: https://github.com/r0man/ring-cors/blob/fe44f9e11565b3e0eeb81c1fabebb6c29e3d077f/src/ring/middleware/cors.clj#L90

Comment: I added allowed methods but it still doesn't do anything

Comment: Works for me: if I run the API on localhost:3000 and execute `curl -vH "Origin: http://localhost:81" localhost:3000/route-a`, I get the Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Methods headers in the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CORS-specific response headers are returned only if the request has an `Origin` header that matches the specified regex (when a request is made using `XMLHttpRequest` in browser, the Origin header is added automatically).

If you try:

```
curl -vH "Origin: http://localhost:81" localhost:3000/route-a
```

(assuming that your API is available on port 3000), you will see that the necessary response headers are added. AJAX requests from `http://localhost:81` should also work.